# How to convert huge table from MyISAM into INNODB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, upgrade, myisam

I have a game DB that was originally created in MySQL 3.x and still have some MyISAM tables.

Due to different reasons (that is a subject for a separate discussion) I want to migrate them to INNODB.

One of the tables has 120 million of rows (120 262 514 to be precise). I've executed it's conversion into INNODB... it was started yesterday and is still going on...

In addition to change the engine i wanted to change type for few fields though. The query is following:

```
ALTER TABLE gb_vfm5.my_table
    CHANGE COLUMN matchId matchId INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CHANGE COLUMN team team INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CHANGE COLUMN pl1 pl1 INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CHANGE COLUMN actionId actionId TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CHANGE COLUMN src src TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CHANGE COLUMN opponent opponent INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, ENGINE = INNODB
```

**Questions:**

1. Why the query execution takes so long? Probably I should 1st change the engine and after that change fields?
2. What is the best/proper way to do such changes?
3. How big is load of this type of conversion to the MySQL server?

P.S. Right now I'm thinking about copying DB into

P.P.S. Definition of table to converted:

```
CREATE TABLE my_moment(
  Id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  matchId INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  mTime TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  team INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  pl1 INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  actionId TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  src TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  pos2 SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  pl2 INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  poss1 SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  poss2 SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  mRes TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  opponent INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  move TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  INDEX actionId (actionId, pl1, mRes),
  INDEX matchId (matchId),
  INDEX NewIndex1 (mRes),
  INDEX NewIndex3 (actionId, pl2),
  INDEX pl1 (pl1),
  INDEX pos2 (pos2),
  INDEX UK_my_table_MatchTeamAction (matchId, team, actionId)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 125433749
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 36
CHARACTER SET cp1251
COLLATE cp1251_general_ci
COMMENT = 'My table description';
```

Comment: You haven't provided us with the table definitions of the underlying table.

Comment: Added. thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: When altering tables, MySQL will create a second table with the new attributes (or new engine type), copy all the first table's rows to the second table, and then replace the first table with the second one. For a large table this operation will take a long time.

Comment: Thanks, it is an option... If you make it as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like to leave unanswered messages, so I'm posting Joshua's suggestion as answer.

> When altering tables, MySQL will create a second table with the new
>   attributes (or new engine type), copy all the first table's rows to
>   the second table, and then replace the first table with the second
>   one. For a large table this operation will take a long time.

So idea behind is create in my own table, move record piece by piece from original table into the new one and upon that rename tables. The last step is to re-create foreign keys.